# Change URL from ?index to /index

Tags: php, url, switch-statement, slash

Today we use a switch for our site to work.

```
switch (key($_GET)) {
  case 'index': include('assets/pages/index-page.php'); break;
  case 'faq': include('assets/pages/faq-page.php'); break;
  ...
}
```

That means that the URL is https://finna.nu/?index
But we want it to be: https://finna.nu/page/index

How do we do that in PHP?
Can we still use the switch we have?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that.
Use [pathinfo()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) in the switch statement to get the extra path trailing the page name.

Comment: Can you show me how?  Reading the document on the link you gave me but didn't understand..

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer. Check out the return value of pathinfo() when you call your script with a trailing path.